# Python -quandl package installation

Tags: python, quandl

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 3.5; I used `pip install quandl` to install quandl package. I am seeing below error.

on the other hand I tried below two methods:

1. download .whl package and provide path where .whl file is located. I am seeing same error as below.

   ```
   Processing ./Documents/Quandl-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   Collecting inflection>=0.3.1 (from Quandl==3.2.0)
   Requirement already satisfied: requests<2.18,>=2.7.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Quandl==3.2.0)
   Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Quandl==3.2.0)
   Collecting more-itertools (from Quandl==3.2.0)
     Using cached more_itertools-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
   Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Quandl==3.2.0)
   Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Quandl==3.2.0)
   Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.14 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from Quandl==3.2.0)
   Installing collected packages: inflection, more-itertools, Quandl
   Exception:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/rr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
       status = self.run(options, args)
     File "/home/rr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
       prefix=options.prefix_path,
     File "/home/rr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
       **kwargs
     File "/home/rr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
       self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
     File "/home/rr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
       isolated=self.isolated,
     File "/home/rr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
       clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
     File "/home/rr/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
       shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
       with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/inflection.py'
   ```
2. other method i tried is use `sudo -apt get install python -3 quandl`. While using this method I am   seeing below error

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   E: Unable to locate package python-quandl
   ```

For method 1: I am unable to understand why I am getting permission denied error message.

For method 2:  Why is it not able to locate package?

I will appreciate any advice on these error messages and also any help in installing this package on python 3.5 in ubuntu 14.04.